# Rank sequences in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table similar like this :

```
User ID creation_time   Clicked Rank
2.30417E+13 10:39:03 AM FALSE   1
2.30417E+13 10:40:35 AM TRUE    1
2.30417E+13 10:40:36 AM TRUE    2
2.30417E+13 10:40:50 AM FALSE   1
2.30417E+13 10:41:20 AM TRUE    1
2.30417E+13 10:41:36 AM TRUE    2
2.30417E+13 10:42:41 AM TRUE    3
2.30417E+13 10:42:41 AM TRUE    4
2.30417E+13 10:44:23 AM TRUE    5
2.30417E+13 10:44:34 AM TRUE    6
2.30417E+13 10:44:36 AM TRUE    7
2.30417E+13 10:44:39 AM TRUE    8
2.30417E+13 10:44:44 AM TRUE    9
2.30417E+13 10:44:50 AM TRUE    10
2.30417E+13 10:44:53 AM TRUE    11
2.30417E+13 10:44:56 AM TRUE    12
2.30417E+13 10:45:05 AM TRUE    13
2.30417E+13 10:45:40 AM FALSE   1
2.30417E+13 10:45:41 AM TRUE    1
2.30417E+13 10:46:07 AM TRUE    2
2.30417E+13 10:46:07 AM TRUE    3
2.30417E+13 10:46:08 AM TRUE    4
```

the rank column is how i would like to rank the rows. in the table i have hundreds of users, and i want to rank each user according to the sequences of clicks/no clicks he done. 
Any idea? i've tried rank , row_number, different setups of them .. cant figure it out.

Comment: Lead (windowfunction/analytic) to look ahead to next value and when false then reset rank to 1.

Comment: Are you using Postgres or Amazon Redshift?  Please tag and title correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a grouping column for the `row_number()`.  This can be calculated as a running sum of the values of the user id and clicked column, where clicked is false.

So:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by userid, clicked, grp order by creation_time) as rank
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when clicked = false then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid order by creation_time) as grp
      from t
     ) t;
```

Sometimes, Amazon requires the windowing clause for window functions, so you might need a `rows between unbounded preceding and current row`.  Postgres does not have this requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not working for me , here is the script :`sum(case when clicked =0 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by user_id order by creation_time asc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as grp`                                                                       and here is the upper query : ` row_number() over (partition by user_id, clicked, grp order by creation_time ) as rank`  the result of rank is just sequence of 1 , for the example table i showed in the questions.

Comment: Could the problem be `clicked = 0`?

Comment: No.. i've tried convert it to binary / used the original false/true.  the grp colum seems to react the changes but the row number just throw ones . the grp is cumulative sum ,and when clicked is false , the number isnt changing (1 2 2 3 4 5 .. )